# OAuth User Registration - ASP.Net 4.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, user-interface, oauth, simplemembership

I'm currently in the beginning stages of developing a website using ASP.Net 4.5 and C#.  I'm wanting to map out the process flow of user registration and authentication.  There's a starter project that uses the WebSecurity framework - with Simple Membership - that includes OAuth integration, allowing users to use Facebook and other logins to access the site.

What special considerations must one consider when using external logins on their website?

--Specialty login and registration pages for each provider used

--Authentication checks -- making sure application access hasn't been revoked during the course of any logged in session

--Re-Authentication screens

--Merging accounts

I'm seeing a bunch of different posts on how to set up ASP.Net and the WebSecurity framework to accept different logins, but not so many on the considerations needed before implementing such functionality

EDIT: This is an MVC site.  Updated post to correct this

Comment: What I'd do is start a new MVC project as it has an vast amount of what you're looking included in the project template, looking at that should give you a lot of clues for doing this in a non MVC site.

Comment: This actually is indeed an MVC site.  I updated the post to clarify; sorry for the confusion.  I know the template indeed has information but it's there to show how to get registration working but not much else (iirc)

Comment: OK, this is actually a VERY wide question.  When I played with the site template I found that it worked right out of the box.  The problem with any of this is that external implementations of things like OpenID and OAuth have been in flux for a long time.  They have settled somewhat now however.  I'd recommend just running with it for now and coming back with more specific questions.  It's non-trivial functionality and hard to anwer such wide questions as a result.

Comment: OK thank you!  I'll close the question then.

Comment: No problem, good luck with it all.